# Cannot Insert SQL Into One Specific Table

Tags: php, sql, insert, phpmyadmin

So I've been trying to insert sql into this one specific table for the past three hours and I think I'm starting to go insane. *I've isolated things I think could be the problem, although if you want more information feel free to ask*

Essentially I currently have two sql tables: `concepts` and `FUideas` (I got really frusturated with it) which are stored in the same database.  When I run the following code:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `concepts` (description) VALUES ('HAI THAR')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

It inserts a row into concepts, **but when i run this code:**

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `FUideas` (description) VALUES ('HAI THAR')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

It does nothing. *And just to further mess with your head:* if you execute this in phpMyAdmin tab:

```
INSERT INTO `FUideas` (description) VALUES ('HAI THAR')
```

**it works!?!?!**

**PLEASE ANY IDEAS, CODE, HACKS? I'M DESPERATE!  *If you have any hunch or clues tell me and I'll try it and report back with the results***

### EDIT

*PHP Myadmin dump of how to create tables:*

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jul 04, 2011 at 11:21 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.91
-- PHP Version: 5.2.9

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;


CREATE TABLE concepts (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  title tinytext NOT NULL,
  `user` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  summary tinytext NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  tags tinytext NOT NULL,
  ip tinytext NOT NULL,
  appreciates tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '4',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jul 04, 2011 at 11:23 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.91
-- PHP Version: 5.2.9

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Table structure for table 'FUideas'
--

CREATE TABLE FUideas (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  description text NOT NULL,
  upvotes text NOT NULL,
  downvotes text NOT NULL,
  appreciated tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  ip tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### FINAL UPDATE

For anyone else looking at this problem, it turns out that I had old code running at the same time which was creating the errors and inconsistencies.

Comment: I don't see how your first statement can work either. You have multiple NOT NULL columns but are only inserting into 1.

Comment: You can use mysql_error([ resource $link_identifier ] ) to see the last error in database.

Comment: Hi @Ash, welcome to the Mysql... that "thing" called database engine, always insert default values: "" for varchar and text, 0000-00-00 for date, 0 for integer, etc...

Comment: @doctore - Ok, fair enough, I've only used MSSQL. Can you tell me the point in specifying `NOT NULL` then?

Comment: @Ash so that if it is undefined it will reurn 0 or "" instead of NULL

Comment: Hi @Ash, in MySQL really the only difference between declaring a field null or not null, is that the database engine fill this field with a "default value", when you don't give a value for it. One point for the integrity of information in MySQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try thiS:

```
mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

If there is a problem with the query (syntax error, or a key violation, etc...), then the die() call will spit out the error message describing the problem.

Comment: Ok and we just entered the [twilight zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone). I did that and it told me I hadn't selected a database.... whoops. So I selected the correct database and it worked... why would it still be able to insert into `concepts` if I had the wrong database selected?

Comment: Put an `or die(...)` after the mysql_select_db() call as well. As a general rule it's always a good idea to check the return values from database calls - assuming a query/call succeeded is poor practice. Even if your sql query syntax is perfect, there's far too many other ways for a query to fail to NOT check return values.

Comment: Wait, the first one doesn't work either, ok I'm just going insane :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `FUideas` (`description`) VALUES ('HAI THAR')";
```

If that doesn't work then i ask, in your SQL to create the table, how come `user` and `date` are quoted, but the other fields aren't?

Comment: `description` is not a reserved word in mysql, so the backticks around it are not necessary.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but it doesn't change anything :( because description isn't a reserved word in mysql. Thanks for the guess though.

Answer (score 1):

Since it works as an admin, my guess is that the username you are using in the connection does not have insert privileges over the FUIdeas table.

Comment: It has GOT to be a priviledge problem. I jsut created his table form the `SQL` above, and ran the query and it worked with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure, but description may be reserved, try..

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `FUideas` (`description`) VALUES ('HAI THAR')";
mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

I guess that would'nt make sense with the first one working...

is my_db the same for both instances?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the SQL-error? I can't see how your first query works since you have a bunch of not null columns without DEFAULT-values.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert single value:

> $sql = "INSERT INTO `concepts`
>   (description) VALUES ('HAI THAR')";

While you have many fields market as `NOT NULL` in your table. You must fill at least **ALL** required fields with one insert statement.
BTW your first "working" expression could not work also if DDL you passed is real.